# $ \frac{\partial}{ \partial t} = \frac 1 2 \Delta \implies $ Brownian Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Apparently, the diff equation : $ \frac{\partial}{ \partial t} = \frac 1 2 \Delta \implies $ Brownian Motion. I.E. all solutions of the equations are brownian motions.

**How ?**

Comment: I think you should look at it the other way around. The probability density of a Brownian Motion obeys the diffusion equation

Comment: Indeed how? Why should a solution of the heat equation be a Brownian motion?

Comment: @LutzLehmann are you asking me ? I read it as a comments in my lecture notes

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\D}{\mathit{\Delta}}$
If you discretize the equation to
$$
u(x,t+\D t)-u(x,t)=\frac{\D t}{2\D x^2}[u(x+\D x,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-\D x,t)]
$$
and then choose the step sizes so that $\D t=\D x^2$, the equation simplifies to
$$
u(x,t+\D t)=\frac12[u(x+\D x,t)+u(x-\D x,t)]
$$
and then
\begin{align}
u(x,t+2\D t)&=\frac14[u(x+2\D x,t)+2u(x,t)+u(x-2\D x,t)]
\\
u(x,t+3\D t)&=\frac14[u(x+3\D x,t)+3u(x+\D x,t)+3u(x-\D x,t)+u(x-3\D x,t)]
\end{align}
etc. down the Pascal's triangle. This can be interpreted as summing over all random walks from $t$ to $t+N\D t$ moving up or down $\D x=\sqrt{\D t}$ with equal probability $\frac12$ in every time step. The limit of these random walks is the Brownian motion.